# Html scripts in react with div id not working

Tags: jquery, html, reactjs

I'm actually working on a React project with voip business and there's a tool that I need to include on my Main component, but that tool is made for html pages.

```
<div id="includedContent"></div>  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>      
   var config = {   
   authorizationUser: '00000000', 
   password : '00000000',  
   options :{ }
   };    

   $(function(){
      $("#includedContent").load("https://path/tool.html");
   });
</script>
```

This code usually goes in html. I need that tool on my Main component ready as it is or I'll need to rework on it in React but I have no time for this.

I have already tried using document.createElement() creating all the scripts and introducing to head with document.head.appendChild() but the div id doesn't seem to work.

```
export default class Tool extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        const script1 = document.createElement("script");
        script1.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js";
        script1.async = true;
        document.head.appendChild(script1);

        const script2 = document.createElement("script");
        script2.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.js";
        script2.async = true;
        document.head.appendChild(script2);

        const script3 = document.createElement("script");
        const script3Text = document.createTextNode("var config={ authorizationUser: '00000000', password : '00000000', options : { }}; $(function(){ $('#includedContent').load('https://path/tool.html');});")
        script3.appendChild(script3Text);
        document.head.appendChild(script3);
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div id="includedContent"></div>
        );
    }
}
```

I need to implement this tool in my Main component, there's some way to do this with this html? OBS.: This tool is 100% secure, made by one of our developers.

Comment: Could you please add an example code of what you have tried? So then it will be easy for us to help you out.

Comment: Have you tried adding it on your `index.html`. This approach will add it to all your react components.

Comment: Updated the question with the code I tried, got the ```<script>``` on head and tried to access with the div but no success. About the index.html, I tried that but the tool can't be in every place, only in a specific component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following would work.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";


function Main() {
  const [toolHtml, setToolHtml] = React.useState("<b>Tool Loading</b>");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const loadTool = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("/tool.html");
        const htmlForTool = await response.text();
        setToolHtml(htmlForTool);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error: ", error);
      }
    };
    loadTool();
  }, []);

  return <div className="App" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: toolHtml }} />;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("includedContent");
ReactDOM.render(<Main />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Equivalent React Class Component is

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";


class Main extends React.Component {
  state = {
    toolHtml: "<b>Tool Loading</b>"
  }

  loadTool = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("/tool.html");
      const htmlForTool = await response.text();
      this.setState({toolHtml: htmlForTool});
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error: ", error);
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadTool();
  }

  render() {
    return <div className="App" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.toolHtml }} />    
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("includedContent");
ReactDOM.render(<Main />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Using `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` is not recommended though. Read [dangerouslySetInnerHtml](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml.) for more details.

[Edit]: To use config.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Main extends React.Component {
  config = {
    authorizationUser: "00000000",
    password: "00000000",
    options: {}
  };
  state = {
    toolHtml: "<b>Tool Loading</b>"
  };

  loadTool = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("/tool.html");
      const htmlForTool = await response.text();

      this.setState({ toolHtml: htmlForTool });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error: ", error);
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadTool().then(() => {
     //Assuming myinput is an input component came with tool.html
      document.getElementById("myinput").value = this.config.authorizationUser;
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="App"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.toolHtml }}
      />
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Main />, rootElement);
```

Comment: It is partially functioning with React Class Component :D That did the trick, but something is missing, how can I get the 'var config' part in that way? I need that to get the tool working.

Comment: Config is a normal js object, if you want to use the values you can use them in your rendered html once html is set. Check the updated answer. Also, if there are any event handlers need to be in html, you have to attach them once the html is fully loaded.

Comment: Worked just fine :D Saved me a lot of work friend, thank you!